# How to enter commands starting with i

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, plugin-vimtex

[vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/wiki/usage#default-mappings) lists some commands like `ie` to be entered in mode `nxo`. How do I do that? What is mode `nxo`? (Usually `i` brings me into insert mode, and `e` then just inserts an `e`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vimtex, the mappings like `ie` are actually vim text objects (not sure about the right vim nomenclature though). They work together with vim operators like `d` (delete).

In particular `ie` stands for any tex environment like `equation`, `itemize`, .... For example, if you cursor is somewhere inside

```
\begin{equation}
    Ax = b
\end{equation}
```

the command `die` will delete everything between `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` and leave you with

```
\begin{equation}\end{equation}
```

.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm! - Now the help texts `<plug>(vimtex-ie) Text object for environments (exclusive).` etc. also make sense. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. I switched to vimtex yesterday and I had exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

N represents Normal mode and O represents operational mode and X represents Ex mode.  Mappings can be done in normal, ex (similar to command line), visual, insert and operational mode as well. 
To know more,
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html

Vim knows to distinguish key mappings and predefined commands. For example, if you have a mapping like `ie` in normal mode, when you press `i`, it waits for some time (timeout) and checks whether you entered `e` so that it can execute the mapping. If you didn't press any key within that time, it goes to insert mode.

So, whatever mapping you have, you have to press the characters in mapping one after the other immediately (within the timeout time). If you do so, that mapping get executed. If you fail to complete the mapping  (fail to press all keys within time), the predefined command with the first key or (first+second key) gets executed.

One example: 
Let's take `di{`. This mapping deletes text inside a `{` and `}` pair. Suppose if you press `d` , it waits for some keys to be pressed. This waiting mode is called operational mode. If you didn't press `i{` within that time, the command is incomplete and gets cancelled.

Comment: I go from normal mode to insert mode immediately on `i`. I also get no timeout after the first `d` if I do `dd`, for example. (Ubuntu 16.04 and vim version 7.4.1689)

Comment: What is the output of `:set timeout` and `:set ttimeout `?

Comment: Both really empty.

Comment: What is the output of `:map ie`? Can you see the plugin's mapping here?

Comment: `:map ie` yields `o ie @<Plug>(vimtex-ie)` and `x ie @<Plug>(vimtex-ie)` - Actually I can use these commands like `ie` after having entered "visual block" mode by pressing `<Ctrl-V>`.

Comment: Yeah, that's Operator-pending mode and Visual mode. `:help mapmode-o`, `:help mapmode-x`.